# Como mandar una imagen de un Activity a otro, en Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, android-imageview

Quiero mandar una imagen de un Activity1 a un Activity2 mediante Intent, y mostrarla en mi Activity2 en KOTLIN

//ASÍ INTENTE MANDARLA AL ACTIVITY2:

```
 fun enviarImagen() {
        var dato = imagen as Int
        val intent = Intent(this@EscaparateActivity, FormularioActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("logo", dato)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

No se si eso esta bien, pero no se como recibirla, por ser de tipo ImageView

Comment: de donde obtienes la imagen en la primera activity?

Comment: La obtengo del xml en el layout asignado a la primer Activity

Comment: creo que es mejor obtenerla de la misma manera que pasarlo en un intent

Comment: cómo se haría eso?

Comment: Es que quiero mostrarla en otro activity diferente donde en su xml tengo asignada otra imageView

Comment: si es una imagen que debe ser compartida entre actividades ¿porque no optas por que sea un asset?

Answer (score 0):

Si la imagen la tienes en los recursos de la aplicación puedes pasar el id del recurso de la imagen. Después en la otra actividad con ese id la vuelves a obtener.

Supongamos que tienes una imagen en la carpeta `/res/drawable/ejemplo.png`. El id para acceder a esa imagen sería `R.drawable.ejemplo`. Puedes pasar ese id a la otra actividad para acceder a esa imagen desde ella.

```
// Actividad 1

val intent = Intent(this, Actividad2::class.java)
intent.putExtra("imagen_id", R.drawable.ejemplo)
startActivity(intent)
```

```
// Actividad 2

val imagenId = intent?.getIntExtra("imagen_id", 0)
val imagen = resources.gatDrawable(imagenId)
```

Answer (score 0):

yo tengo el mismo problema, pero en mi caso la imagen viene de un recyclerView
mi problema es cuando intento recibir esa imagen que fue seleccionada del recyclerview
Tambien envio 2 TextView que no tengo inconvenientes al recibirlos:

// activity 1(  envio la foto):

```
   adaptador = AdaptadorPantalla2(estanterias, object : OnItemClickListner {
        override fun onItemClick(vista: View, position: Int) {
           Toast.makeText(applicationContext, estanterias.get(position).nombreProducto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(this@Pantalla2Estanterias, DetalleMuebles::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("Nombre", estanterias.get(position).nombreProducto)
            intent.putExtra("Codigo", estanterias.get(position).articulo)
            intent.putExtra("Foto", estanterias.get(position).foto)
            startActivity(intent)
            }
```

// Activity 2 (Envio los parametros) :

class DetalleMuebles : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalle_muebles)

    val intent = intent


    var nombrep = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nombreMueble)
    var fotop = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.fotoDetalle)
    var codigop = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.codigoMueble)

    nombrep?.text = intent.getStringExtra("Nombre")
    fotop?.setImageResource(intent.getStringExtra("Foto").toInt())
    codigop?.text = intent.getStringExtra("Codigo")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No creo que sea posible, y de ser posible tampoco sería lo viable, ya que en su momento intenté pasar las imágenes con un método rebuscado usando la interface "Parcelable" y me decía que el parámetro era demasiado grande, puede que haya sido por el método o por las capacidades del intent.

Aún así no me di por vencido y encontré una manera de hacerlo aunque no creo que sea lo ortodoxo, y lo hice de la siguiente manera:

// Primero declaras estas variables las cuales te permitirán guardar datos (String, int, boolean, etc.) en el espacio local de tu aplicación recuerda hacer los respectivos importes

```
            val prefs = androidx.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext)
            val editor = prefs.edit()
```

// Luego conviertes tu imagen Bitmap en un Array de bytes de la siguiente manera

```
            val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            nombreImagenEnBitmap.imagen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)
            val byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
```

//Tu anterior array de bytes lo conviertes en un string base64

```
            val encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

//Finalmente eso lo guardas en el espacio local de tu aplicación

```
            editor.putString("<Nombre de tu imagen>", encoded)
            editor.apply()
```

Con esto ya habrás terminado con el activity que enviará tu imagen. Ahora en nuestro activity receptor convertiremos ese String base64 a una imagen de tipo Bitmap de la siguiente manera:

// En tu Segundo Activity también deberás de declarar de igual manera la variable "prefs" para poder hacer lo siguiente

```
            val byteCode = Base64.decode(prefs.getString("<Nombre de tu imagen>", ""), Base64.DEFAULT)
            val image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteCode, 0, byteCode.size)
```

//La variable "image" es tu imagen en Bitmap, con lo cual ya podrás utilizarla en tu otra actividad de la manera que veas conveniente, incluso este proceso te podrá servir para más de un cambio de actividad ya que está almacenado localmente

Esta es la única manera que he encontrado de hacer ese intercambio de información de todo lo que he investigado, espero te sirva aunque he llegado bastante tarde.